# Show date format in Excel as the OS default

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2011

Is there a way in Excel (2007 and up) to set the date format of a column to the date format of the OS locales. The data entered in this column is a date (imported from a database date field).

For example I enter `2003-01-02 00:00:00` (Jan 2nd 2003) I want to see `01/02/2003 00:00:00` in the USA and `02.01.2003 00:00:00` in Germany when I open my spreadsheet (without updating the column date format).

Answer (score 0):

If set up correctly, these can change with the regional settings of Windows. Here is an article from Excel Semi-Pro which explains it well. [Regional Date Formats in Excel](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/)